# How to tell if a Demultiplexer's output values are maintained from datasheet

Tags: multiplexer

I want to know how can i tell from a Demultiplexer's datasheet that it maintains the output logic level after the address inputs have been changed.

**EDIT: I do not have any datasheet to post since I have not found any demultiplexer with the 'latching' feature that I want. What I am asking here is how to understand that a Demux has this latching feature from looking at a datasheet**

Example: Say i want to turn on 3 leds:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgnR8i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But after the LED1 is turned ON, and I focus (point on) the second led, I want the first led to stay ON.

I tried searching on the datasheets for the keyword "Latching" or "latch" but it found nothing. Maybe i just searched on the wrong datasheets (like [this one](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/74HC_HCT4051-1389023.pdf)) , or is there another keyword?

In [this website](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_3.html) also says: **Also some have latches built into their outputs to maintain the output logic level after the address inputs have been changed** So I know some of them have this feature.

Comment: please add a link to the datasheet ... add to the post, NOT in comments

Comment: I cannot find a Demultiplexer with a 'latching' feature, so i do not have any datasheet to post. (I ended up adding one datasheet tho)

Comment: ok then ... yes, the multiplexer's datasheet should show whether the output is latched

Comment: Your drawing appears to be missing an output. By your drawing you have 3 outputs, out0 is missing. In is selected by the binary pattern on S0 and S1 so if that pattern changes so does the output. You have selected the wrong part. Consider a serial input part such as a 74HC595 then you can latch what outputs you want. A demultiplexer gives you typically x out of y and does not remember the last state.

Comment: in the link you provided, `table 3` shows that it does not latch outputs

Comment: search for `addressable latch`

Comment: Look at the internal schematic, e.g. page 2 here. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls013a/sdls013a.pdf Note the absence of a register or latch. This one doesn't. Now repeat for your choice of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, demultiplexers follow their select inputs and don't remember previous states. They don't have storage. There's nothing to 'tell' from the datasheet. It's like asking if a NAND gate can hold its output (it can't), so there would be no statement about that.

If you want that functionality of driving more than one LED at a time, consider that you have 3 MCU pins driving 3 LEDs - why not just use the MCU pins directly?

Comment: the OP asked `how to determine function from datasheet?`

Comment: Well here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_3.html It says: **Also some have latches built into their outputs to maintain the output logic level after the address inputs have been changed**

Comment: Yes, this part: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4351.pdf has an address latch. That's not going to solve your problem of wanting to light more than one LED at a time. What is your point?

Comment: Hm maybe I need to make a new question oh how to light up miltiple leds with one pin.

I do not use the pins directly cause I have limited pins, I am running out of pins

Comment: Try an I2C expander, like the PCF8574.

Comment: Or a SPI driver... there are many to choose from. Example: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NLSF595-D.PDF